# How to substitute a function argument with a string in c++?

Tags: c++, string

I'm new to c++, and am trying to make a fullscreen setting in SFML. But nothing I tried works.

Working code:

```
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1920, 1080, 32), "title", sf::Style::Fullscreen);
```

Code that would look like what I am looking for (but doesn't work):

```
string str1 = "sf::Style::Fullscreen";
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1920, 1080, 32), "title", str1);
```

Comment: Why would you expect passing a `std::string` as the third parameter would be valid when it expects `Uint32`? https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1RenderWindow.php#aebef983e01f677bf5a66cefc4d547647

Comment: How could this work when that value needs to be *compiled*? Remember, C++ is strongly typed, it doesn't allow you to sling in any old thing, especially not arbitrary strings. There's no `eval` here. You either write a conversion function from `std::string` to whatever type that argument expects, or you just do it like you did on the first line.

Comment: This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). *Why* are you looking for that?

Comment: Why you are passing enum value as a string instead as enum as in first example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3rd parameter of `sf::RenderWindow` is a `Uint32` (at least that's what the documentation says), but you are trying to pass a string which is rather pointless.

You probably want something like this:

```
Uint32 mystyle = sf::Style::Fullscreen;
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1920, 1080, 32), "title", mystyle);
```

or better:

```
auto mystyle = sf::Style::Fullscreen;
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1920, 1080, 32), "title", mystyle);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't convert a string to an enum with the same name. Enums are basicly ints in runtime, the name of the enum is lost when compileing. The closest you can get is making a `const map<string,enum>` and filling it up manually.  eg.:

```
enum En{a,b,c};
const map<string,En> mp{
    {"a",En::a},
    {"b",En::b},
    {"c",En::c}
};
...
void foo(En);
string str;
...
foo(mp[str]);
```